# How tocompare the dataminig classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am a naive to data mining.I want to survey these classifiers Decision tree, naive bayes, KNN and C-Means.How can i compare between them. 
How can i observe the strengths and weakness of each classifiers.
can any one help?

Comment: C-Means is not a classifier, but an unsupervised clustering algorithm. For the drawbacks and benefits **read an introductory book**. It should point out the benefits and drawbacks.

Comment: @AhmedHamed there is no best classifier , so this is too broad and will most probably be closed. You should look into one of the many introductory books.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you use two sets :

- **Training set** is used to build your classifier
- **Test set** is used to test and validate your classifier

You can simply build all your classifiers with the same training set.
Then, apply the same test set to your classifiers and compare the results (well vs wrong classified).

ps : There is no best classifier. All results will depends on your training set properties.

Comment: There is no *generally best* classifier. On most data sets, one of the many classifiers, when carefully trained, will be "best" according to some metric.